# Git repositories synchronization

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have two Git repositories

1. Repo1
2. Repo2, which has 90% code same as of Repo1

Development happens on both repos. Any changes which happen on repo1, need to be pushed to repo2 also.
What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Extract the common code to a library both depend on? Make repo1 a *dependency* of repo2? A *submodule* of repo2?

Comment: The common code can change in both the repos as time progresses.. i.e we are continuously developing on both the repos. Will this work in that case also?

Comment: That sounds like a horrible mess. You shouldn't have the same code in active development in two places, make repo 2 *depend on*, not duplicate, repo 1.

Answer (score 0):

In repo1, do this:

```
git remote add repo2 url_of_repo2
git fetch
```

At this point, you have all branches of repo2 available.  Merge them add usual and push them, probably with `-f`.